# Congratulations, Did hits the 100K!!

Tags: discussion, reputation, specific-user

#### "[Did](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/6179/did)" is now one of the top 5 users of Math.SE

He hit the reputation score of 100K today!!

Congratulations to him from the community!

Comment: Congratulations to Did, and a thank you for your devotion to the tags within the realm of probability theory and stochastic processes. Also thank you for taking your time to help others improve their answers - this has been particularly rewarding for me.

Comment: Congrats, Did! I really appreciate having you here.

Comment: Did, congratulations too! I too appreciate your help! Stefan has said what I want to say.

Comment: Many congrats, @Did.  That is quite the accomplishment.  I for one appreciate all of the illumination you have provided on some of my derivations.

Comment: He did it. Congratulations.

Comment: Did is one of the most impressive contributors on MSE, in my opinion.

Comment: **Did**, **did** you just **did** this? I'm so happy **Did** **did** it.

Comment: Also Did did downvoted more than 10k.

Answer (score 34):

I guess we can assume that

> [$$\large \mathsf{W}$$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/74383/8348)

stands for "Wow!"

Congrats!

Comment: this is a great answer by did!

Comment: It feels weird to get that.

Comment: "WOW" $\times 100$

Comment: Congratulations Did. :-)